# Frequent Sequential Patterns

Tags: r, gsp, apriori

What would be the best way to get the sequential pattern for such data in R :

[image]

The idea is to get the frequency of letters in process 1,2, and 3. Is there GSP function that can do that ? any insight or tutorial is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use an `apply` and `table` combo (provided you read your data into R):

```
dat <- data.frame(process1 = c('A', 'B', 'A', 'A', 'C'), process2 = c('B', 'C', 'B', 'B', 'A'), process3 = c('C', 'C', 'A', 'B', 'B'))
apply(dat, 2, table)
#  process1 process2 process3
#A        3        1        1
#B        1        3        2
#C        1        1        2
```

`apply` iterates through the columns of `dat` (this is what argument `2` refers to) and applies `table` to each, which counts each unique element. see help pages for `*apply` family of functions for more info.

d.b's solution above, `lapply(dat, table)`, does the same thing but returns a list rather than a matrix.

Comment: Thank you @stas g. That's helpful.